# Error while loading image

Tags: java, image, netbeans

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import model.Map;


public class MyView {

    private BufferedImage img = null;
    private static MyPanel panel;

    //init image

    try{
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("/src/minepic/start.png"));
    } catch (IOException e){ 
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I want to load an PNG image from the src directory but I don't know why it doesn't work, anyone can help me?

Error in command "try catch" and NetBeans say "unreported exception IOexception; must be caught or declared to be thrown"
One more, even i declared img as a BufferedImage before, but in command "try catch" img just like didn't declared because in NetBeans it doesn't become green, still black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with the code:

1. It is incomplete. The braces are not matched.
2. you have written code outside main method (possible but not recommended)
3. To read the image from src folder (which is a part of your class path) use the below snippet:

   ```
   Inputstream is = MyView.class.getResourceAsStream("minepic/start.png");
   if(is==null){
       is = MyView.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("minepic/start.png");
   }
   img = ImageIO.read(is);
   ```